# How to continuously update data in zTree on database side

Tags: php, ajax, function, ztree

I am trying to use zTree_v3 in PHP.

However, I do not know where to put update function when a node is updated.

I know that I can put update function in some events.

But, it seems to me that is wrong.

Comment: Nope. I want to update database when node has changed.

Comment: Well....what I do not know is where I should put update function when zTree node is updated. So, this is before the database.

Comment: Possibly, you are misunderstanding me.I am talking about this https://github.com/zTree/zTree_v3 . So, this is not database related.